# Python Opencv 2.4.X Videocamera error

Tags: python-2.7, opencv, image-processing

i am new to the opencv python programming i just followed a tutorial on youtube and ran the ready made code on my windows machine. my installation steps are all correct but i am not able to use my inbuilt laptop camera with the ball tracking or any of the code. and if i change the line in the code

from

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
```

to

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('video.mp4')
```

everything works just great. just that  i am not able to use the laptops camera and this is the error i get

> OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (scn == 3 || scn == 4) in cv::cvtColor, file ........\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\color.cpp, line 3739
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:/Python Programs Pycharm/Opencv_test.py", line 11, in 
>       gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
>   cv2.error: ........\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\color.cpp:3739: error: (-215) scn == 3 || scn == 4 in function cv::cvtColor

and finally this is my code i used from stack overflow just to test my video feed

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while(True):

        #Capture Frame by Frame
        ret, frame = cap.read()

        # our operations on the frame come here
        gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

        #Display the resulting frame
        cv2.imshow('frame', gray)
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
           break

#When everything done, release the capture 
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I cant write a comment since I lack reputation. there is nothing wrong with your code. But the camera is not found. try different adresses like `cap = cv2.VideoCapture(1)` or check your camera hardware.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the error comes from when you try to recolor it. You should add a check like

```
if not ret or not frame:
    break
```

that will confirm that your camera is not giving you any input. It will also tell you when a video ends, so it's just a good idea in general to have that. If that's not the problem, try printing out the shape of the frame `print(frame.shape)`, it should be (W, L, 3).

I also see you tagged this question python2.7. Support for python2.7 is ending soon, so I would recommend using python3 as it would also allow you to perform greater tasks on frames asynchronously with asyncio.